# Create multiple DataFrame from dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to create multiple dataframes from a larger one called 'df' by partitioning it every six weeks, I managed to do such a separation, however they are stored inside a 'd' dictionary. However, I need them to be left out of this. Tried with pd.dict_to_df but it didn't work.

[What I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMKQb.png)

```
# DataFrame creation after six weeks
d = {}
# np.arange(start, end + step, step) 
for week, data in df.groupby(pd.cut(df['week'], np.arange(0, 52+6, 6))): # group and cut by week
    #d[f'df{week}'] = data
    d[f'df{len(d.items())}'] = data
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYV5E.png)

The dictionary that i have. (I need 'df0', not a d['df0'])

Comment: No, you really don't want to create separate variables for them.  If you plan on 4 sets of six weeks, and the next run has 5 sets, your code will break.  In this case, a list would be better than a dictionary, so `section[0]` gives you the df for the first six weeks.

Comment: Try `dict_of_dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(pd.cut(df['week'], np.arange(0, 52+6, 6)))))`

Comment: @ScottBoston I got a dict with keys 'dict_keys([Interval(0, 6, closed='right'), Interval(6, 12, closed='right'),...' doesn't look better :(

Comment: Oh.. use labels in pd.cut...

Comment: Or pd.cut the weeks first, then factorize the results and groupby that factorized value.